# PHP PDO error messages

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I'm not too good in programming but I'm trying to make a login for my site. I've researched a bit and PDO was supposed to be safest for calling mySQL queries.

The problem is I don't get it. I've created a function and got this 2 errors.
First is probably related to another function in functions.php but I'm not sure why.
I've read something about the second one but did not get what I'm supposed to do.

> Errors:
>
> 1: Warning: Missing argument 1 for userData(), called in page.php on
>   line 34 and defined in functions.php on line 164
>
> 2:Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   functions.php on line 165

This is the function I'm trying to run

```
    function userData(){
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['username']); 
            $stmt->execute();  
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($username);
            $fetch_stmt=$stmt->fetch();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username);
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $email=$fetch_stmt['email'];
                return array($username,$email);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

This function should return an array of user data from database.

Comment: Where  is your database connection?? and how  it pass to function??

Comment: Can you show what is on the lines 34 and 165?

Comment: can you please share how did you call your function ?

Comment: Line 34 $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
Line 165  if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1")) {

Comment: I don't see a call to `userData` function on line 34? Are you sure about the code and the error? Also, I don't see that `userData` accepts any arguments.

Comment: Also, you're saying that you're using [PDO](https://secure.php.net/pdo), but in your code you're using [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/mysqli). These are different things.

Comment: where are you calling the function. kindly mention how you are calling it.

Comment: @AlexanderGuz I've renamed $username to $user function and the error was gone. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean how I'm trying to get results it's with $arrayt=userData(); echo $arrayt[1];

Comment: yes. what you mentioned is correct.

Comment: do you got it fixed. i think

Comment: @AlexanderGuz Also if that's not PDO is it still safe or should I try to use PDO? I've copied a part of the code and changed it. But it said it was PDO :P

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan I still have the second error and there are no results returning.

Comment: just use print_r($arrayt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as I have already mentioned in comments, you're using [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/mysqli) ant not [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

But it doesn't have anything to do with you errors.

Not sure about the missing argument error, but it seems like you have an argument defined in `userData`, but calling it without the argument.

The second error is about the [variable scope](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Your connection handler, here it is `$mysqli` is undefined inside the function `userData`, because it tries to find a local variable `$mysqli` and fails. You have to either pass the handler inside the function as a parameter, or restructure your code in a way, that you can get the handler from the other place.

Comment: function check_login($mysqli) {
 This is how my other function is using it. And that function works. If I add $mysqli here it still outputs the same error.

Comment: Adding where? To the call of the method? But do you add it the function declaration? It should be in function declaration like `function userData($mysqli)` and in calling code `userData($mysqli)`;

Comment: You're right. I forgot to add $mysqli to page.php where I'm calling. Thanks! Works now. Also had to change some sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and see if it helps:

```
    <?php 

    //DATABASE CONNECTION CONFIGURATION:
    defined("HOST")     or define("HOST",   "localhost");           //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-HOST
    defined("DBASE")    or define("DBASE",  "_TEST_");              //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB NAME
    defined("USER")     or define("USER",   "root");                //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-USER
    defined("PASS")     or define("PASS",   "root");                //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-PASS


    function getUserData(){
        $dbh            = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='. DBASE,USER,PASS);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :uName LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bindParam(':uName', $_SESSION['username']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        //YOU MAY JUST RETURN $result & ACCESS ALL DATA IN IT USING OBJECTION ORIENTATED APPROACH LIKE: $email = $result->email;
        if(!empty($result)){
            //return array($_SESSION['username'], $result->$result->email);
               return $result;
        }                
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in functions.php on line 170

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known' in functions.php:170 Stack trace: #0 functions.php(170): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=HOST...', 'USER2', 'PASS2') #1 page.php(34): userData(NULL) #2 /index.php(22): include_once('/srv/disk7/2110...') #3 {main} thrown in functions.php on line 170

Comment: Try the Code again @Studio DnB    I just edited it. The Problem was because of USER2, PASS2 Constants... Just remove the "2" and it will work... ***But, please be careful to use your own Database Connection Information***

Comment: I think this works. But as I try to echo the results now I get Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string